# Finding index numbers in a Python list?

Tags: python, list

If I have a list like this:

```
name_lst = ['Karen', 'Katrina', 'Karen', 'Kareem', 'F']
```

Where:

```
first_name = "Karen"
first_letter = "F"
```

I want to find the indexes of any names that are not "first_name" nor "first_letter". So, I want my output to look like this:

```
print(output)
#[1, 2]
```

So far, my code looks like this, which doesn't quite work:

```
index_name = [i for i, d in enumerate(name_lst) if d != first_name or first_letter]
print(index_name)
```

I feel like this is a simple fix, but I'm not able to figure out where I'm going wrong. Would appreciate any help - thanks!

Comment: The sub-expression `if d != first_name or first_letter` is not doing what you think.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true

Comment: the expression `d != first_name or first_letter` is *always true*.

Comment: In any case, "I want to find the indexes of any names that are not "first_name" nor "first_letter"" is not really a clear requirement. Do you mean *that doesn't start with first_letter?*

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the name starts with `first_letter` using the `startswith` string method. Also you need to `and` the result of both conditions.

```
index_name = [i for i, d in enumerate(name_lst) if d != first_name and ! d.startswith(first_letter)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name_lst = ['Karen', 'Katrina', 'Karen', 'Kareem', 'F']
first_name = "Karen"
first_letter = "F"
index_name = [i for i, d in enumerate(name_lst) if d != first_name and d != first_letter]
print(index_name)
```

output

```
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't chain multiple (un)equal checks - use a list of elements to exclude instead.

```py
index_name = [i for i, d in enumerate(name_lst) if d not in [first_name, first_letter]]
```